# trying to Close the Advertisement window in webpage

Tags: java, selenium

i Automate the "makemytrip.com" site then one Advertisement window comes and i'm trying to close that window so that i can perform other operations on webpage webelements

i'm using
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class="close"]").click();
to close that advertiment window but it is not working

Comment: Please show us ALL your code

Answer (score 0):

This is because the pop up is inside a frame with title = 'notification-frame-~55852cba. you need to first switch to that frame then click on the close button. after that you have to switch back to the default content